# Keras Autotuner how to spit out best value at the end of run

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to use keras autotuner to find the best value for my NN's dense layer. While the tuner is running, it gives me the proper output, shown below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xdE9.png)

However, immediately after the last epoch, it returns the following shown below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sprMi.png)

Besides watching the `tuner.search` run, is there any way I can get keras to print out the 'best value so far' or any of the other statistics it finds on the completion of the autotuner epochs?

My entire model arch is built as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paADt.png)

I tried Keras Hyperband tuner as kt.Hyperband.

I'm expecting output of all statistics, but I only got the best val_accuracy at the end of the last epoch.

Comment: Please include code and output as text, not as links to images.

Answer (score 0):

add this below your tuner search:

```
# Get the optimal hyperparameters
best_hps=tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]

print(f"""
The hyperparameter search is complete. The optimal number of units in the first densely-connected
layer is {best_hps.get('units')} and the optimal learning rate for the optimizer
is {best_hps.get('learning_rate')}.
""")
```

Here you can see that you can get your hyperparameters from tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(). This returns a dictionary with the results. You can also use best_hps.values to see what else is in there.

Furthermore there is

```
`tuner.results_summary(num_trials=10)`

#Display tuning results summary.
#The method prints a summary of the search results including the hyperparameter values and evaluation results for each trial.
```

More information can be found here:
https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/tuners/base_tuner/#results_summary-method